# Set native Jelly Bean dialer and contacts for Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: contacts, samsung, phone-app

The stock Samsung dialer and contacts (developed by Samsung) is waaay too laggy for me to use it. Actually it takes seconds to navigate through the tabs of logs, favorites or the contact list. (Got about 10 pictures and 10 custom ringtones in 70 contacts, so there's not that much data to handle.) It was actually laggy from the first time I used it. Got Nova launcher instead of the crappy and laggy TouchWiz. In my opinion, every Samsung application is a piece of something brown.

Can I - somehow - force the OS to use the stock Jelly Bean dialer and contact app, or is it got replaced by Samsung's crapware?

Thanks for the input!

Comment: I don't thing the "stock jelly bean dialer" is part of the system. What about trying with a rom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung ROM doesn't have the stock AOSP dialer and contacts app. It has Touchwiz themed dialer and contacts app. This is one of the most glitchy and slowest of dialer apps out there.

1. Try the [Swipe Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mb.swipedial&hl=en) if you care to. It has good reviews and seems to be working fine across the board.
2. Another option will be to port AOSP dialer as in Cyanogenmod. This is advanced stuff and you'll need knowledge of ADB. [Try it out](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2115407) if you want.
3. The easiest way out is to flash a custom ROM. Try Cyanogenmod, AOKP, Paranoid Android, etc. There are several others too. Try XDA Developers forums for more in depth info.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I accept it! I'm going to try out your first two suggestions.